# How to convert yyyymmddThhmmss to mutable date time type in shell script?

Tags: bash

My bash script is looking at a date-time string that looks like: `yyyymmddThhmmss`, for example `20160414T033407`.

I wish to convert this string into date-time format such that I can, for example, change time zone. Currently I am hard-parsing this string and do a -n on the hour to convert the timestamp to my current timezone. However, I see that I have take into account of rolling hours to next days, etc. What is a better approach to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Date doesn't allow "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS", but it does "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS", so:

```
D="20100101123456"
date -d "${D:0:8} ${D:8:2}:${D:10:2}:${D:12:2}"
```

Comment: Nice use of [Substring Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) however in the OP there is a "T" in the string, yyyymmddThhmmss e.g. 20160414T033407 and your answer does not address this!

Comment: It also depends on what version of `date` you are using. BSD `date` lets you specify an input format using the same fields as the output.

Comment: `D="20160414T033407"; date -d "${D:0:8} ${D:9:2}:${D:11:2}:${D:13:2}"`

Answer (score 0):

Could break it out with sed and repeat it back in a format other tools will understand.

```
$ echo '20160414T033407' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'
2016-04-14 03:34:07
```

And then feed it to date to get it out in a format you like, for example Unix timestamp:

```
$ date --date="$(echo '20160414T033407' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/')" +%s
1460630047
```